# Object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, seam2, seam-conversation

I'm using Seam Framework. I have 2 Entity:

**Request.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SRV_REQUEST")
public class Request {

private Long id;

@Id 
@Column(name = "ID_")
public Long getId() {
   return id;
}
```

and **RequestEvent.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SRV_REQUEST_EVENT")
public class RequestEvent {

private Long id;
private Request request;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "ID_")
public Long getId() {
   return id;
}

@ManyToOne
public Request getRequest() {
   return request;
}
```

When I do this transaction:

```
Request request = new Request();
// I have to set ID manually
request.setId(12345);

entityManager.persist(request);

RequestEvent event = new RequestEvent();
event.setRequest(request);

entityManager.persist(event);
```

I got this error:

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: kz.gov.mci.ipsc.services.RequestEvent.request -> kz.gov.mci.ipsc.services.Request
```

Comment: I guess adding entityManager.flush() after entityManager.persist(request) is not an option

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    Request request = new Request();
    // I have to set ID manually
    request.setId(12345);

    entityManager.persist(request);

    entityManager.flush();//this point is important

    RequestEvent event = new RequestEvent();
    event.setRequest(request);

    entityManager.persist(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} on getRequest method

Comment: After adding this I got this error: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "srv_request_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id_)=(2000703891) already exists. However in the database there is no such request entry.

Comment: I guess if you wanna set Id manually you need flush(Save your entity before assign it)

Comment: Use entityManager.flush().

Comment: add  {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE} and remove first persist